# Каким способом образовано слово опенок

Tags: словообразование

Каким способом образовано слово опенок

Answer (score 1):

Опёнок - гриб, растущий на пне, вокруг пня,значит,от слова пень с помощью приставки о и суфф.-ок- Суф.-приставочный.

Comment: Опёнок - это хорошо, правильно, но вопрос, насколько я понимаю, касается опенка, лёгкого кусочка сала, побывавшего в жировой пене (вот что такое буква "ё"!)

Comment: Не слышала такого. Это что - диалект? профессионализм?

Comment: А куда девается корень ПЕН во мн. числе (опята)?

Comment: Извините, @Людмила, это выдумка, желание подчеркнуть значимость буквы "ё": надо ставить две точки над буквой там, где они нужны. Но я переборщил (это областное слово? что оно означает?): в слове "опенок" разночтений нет.

Comment: Форма опята возникла под влиянием таких слов, как жеребенок — жеребята, котенок — котята, где суффикс -енок в ед. числе меняется на -ята во множественном. Звуковое сходство телёнок-жеребёнок-маслёнок-опёнок в единственном числе привело к образованию сходной формы и во множественном числе. В результате изменился и состав слова опенок , как говорят языковеды, произошло переразложение основы: суффикс  увеличился до -енок, а корень уменьшился. Другие учёные(Потиха)считают, что опёнок - всё слово корень, как и опят/а